# Android Animation positioning Problems

Tags: android, xml, animation

I'm trying to make two translate animations in android and having problems with them:

1. I'm trying to display an image entering from one side, and exiting the other, and to do repeatedly for a few minutes.   I can see a moving, but every time the animation begins - i see a blink of the image for a millisecond.

This is my layout xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/anim_image" android:src="@drawable/movimage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"  android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is my anim xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
 android:fromDegrees="40" android:toDegrees="-40" android:toYScale="0.0"
 android:pivotX="40%" android:pivotY="30%" android:duration="4000" />
     <set>
        <translate 
            android:fromXDelta="200%p" android:toXDelta="-150%p" android:fromYDelta="20%"
            android:toYDelta="10%" android:duration="4000" android:zAdjustment="bottom" />
    </set>
 </set>
```

And in my java class i've created a countdowntimer which every onTick calls:
    image.startAnimation(anim);

I also tried to listen to the animation:
        anim.setAnimationListener(this);

And add to the onAnimationEnd:
        image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

But it didn't help me.
Does anyone know what can i do to fix it?

--

1. I'm trying to show a "falling star" image - i've created a small png file (30px*30px) and im trying to position it in one edge of the screen and let it move to the other and dissapear.   But every code i write in the anim XML doesn't doing it!
   Can anyone help me with writing the animation correctly?

I've wrote: translate 
            android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:fromYDelta="0%p"
            android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="500"

And it didn't work..

---

**edit: I've found a solution:**

I've found what was wrong.   I've wrote a code with CountDownTimer for repeating, instead of using the animation's repeat option.  I've changed my XML to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:startOffset="1000"
>
    <rotate
            android:repeatCount="infinite" android:repeatMode="restart" android:fillAfter="false"
            android:fromDegrees="40" android:toDegrees="-40" android:toYScale="0.0"
            android:pivotX="40%" android:pivotY="30%" android:duration="4000" />
     <set>
        <translate 
            android:repeatCount="infinite" android:repeatMode="restart" android:fillAfter="false"
            android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:fromYDelta="20%"
            android:toYDelta="10%" android:duration="4000" android:zAdjustment="bottom" />
    </set>
 </set>
```

and now it works without those blinks in the screen.
Also for the falling star, i've changed the XML to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate 
            android:repeatCount="infinite" android:repeatMode="restart" android:fillAfter="false"
            android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:fromYDelta="0%p"
            android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="2500" android:zAdjustment="bottom" />
     <set>
     <alpha 
        android:repeatCount="infinite" android:repeatMode="restart" android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="2500" />
    </set>
 </set>
```

and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the imageView comes back to its original position after the animation is completed. You can try having `android:fillAfter="true|false"`(try one of it) in the xml of the translate animation. or try `setFillAfter(boolean)` on the animation object if you are loading it using the `AnimationUtils`.

Comment: OK i've found a solution.   I've tried to write my own loop displaying instead of using android's code.  I've removed the timer, and added to the animation the following code: android:repeatCount="infinite" android:repeatMode="restart" android:fillAfter="false"    it works great.

Comment: Ive found another problem - the method onAnimationRepeat is never being called. I think its a bug in android platform.

Comment: how did you load the animation and set the animation listener?

Comment: anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.move);
     anim.setAnimationListener(this);